# Optimize an import method with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For an Import I need To add an huge amount of bId to an MyClassA instance

```
foos = json.loads(self.request.get('foos'))
for foo in foos  :
    a = MyClassA()
    a.id = foo["id"]
    a.name = foo["name"]
    for bId in foo["stringWithAllBidsForA"].split(";") :
                        tmp = B.gql("WHERE id = '"+bId +"'").get()
                        if tmp :
                            a.bList.append(tmp.key())
    a.put()
```

I sure it's lazy but How can I optimize that code.

I'm thinking to add (indexed=True) in id field for B, and key-only for the B gql query  and the batch datastore put.
But I don't know how to do that.

**edit :**

I replaced `b.id = bId by b = MyClassB(key_name= bId)`

so now I do :

```
a.bList.append( foo["stringWithAllBidsForA"].split(";"))
```

I get encoding probleme transforming str to key I tried
with `encoded= foo["stringWithAllBidsForA"].split(";")[0]`

Whats wrong? is not possible to decoded > split > cast to key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `key_name=bId` when storing `B` instance, instead of a separate `id` indexed property, you should be able to do a batch get instead of a datastore query using [Model.get_by_key_name](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name)

```
Model.get_by_key_name(list_of_b_ids)
```

You could also batch put operation using [db.put](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html)

```
db.put(list_of_a_models)
```

Comment: is Model.get_by_key_name(list_of_b_ids) compatible with key only and how should I call it?

Comment: `get_by_key_name` takes a list of key names, it is an equivalent of `db.get` for a specific Entity kind.

Comment: are you sure is getting only key names because in the doc it's written : "Gets the model instance (or instances) for the given key name (or names)"

Comment: It fetch the corresponding entities, given a list of key names. Key only only make sense for queries where don't know the keys in advance. If you already knows the keys, no need to get them :)

Comment: I will try your solution tonight, and I valid it then.

Comment: Can you ask a separate question?